# Gradle intermittently not running TestNG tests

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, gradle, testng

I'm currently experiencing some strange behavior using Gradle to run my TestNG Java tests. Each run, it seems that a random number of tests don't even get built. They are not appearing in the test report nor are they in the Jenkins console output. They show up as being checked out of the current SVN revision, but from what I can see, are not even built.

Oddly enough, this is only happening with the tests designated to run in Chrome. The product I'm testing has full support for Chrome and only partial support for Firefox so that's why there is an exclude for the 'chrome' groups in the build file. This wasn't previously occurring but my only updates have been Selenium Webdriver and Chromedriver.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.37.0"
    compile "org.testng:testng:5.14.10"
    testCompile('org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.testng'
    }
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
    compile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:1.8.1"
}

//initialize thread count variable for parallel testing and default to 1
def threadCount = System.getProperty("MAXTHREADS", "1")

tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 1
    forkEvery = 1000
    ignoreFailures = false

    // Pass all system properties to the tests
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()

    // Makes the standard streams (err and out) visible at console when running tests
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    exclude '**/tasks/'
    exclude '**/quarantine/'

    classpath += configurations.testCompile
}

task firefox(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full" // default is "short"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/firefox")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/firefox")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'firefox')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task chrome(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/chrome")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/chrome")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'chrome')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task internetExplorer(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome'
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/internetExplorer")
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/internetExplorer")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'internetExplorer')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task applylicense(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/applyLicense")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/applyLicense")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/ApplyLicense.class'
}

task uatsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/uatSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/uatSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/UatSetup.class'
}

task restsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/restSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/restSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/RestSetup.class'
}

task soapsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/soapSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/soapSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/SoapSetup.class'
}

task selenium(type: Test) {
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/selenium")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/selenium")

    include '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/webdriver/'
    exclude '**/*$*', '**/Abstract*'
    exclude '**/messagepanel/'
    exclude '**/propertylibrary/'
}

javadoc() {
    title = "xMod Page Objects API"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.7'
}
```

Is it possible that these updates may have caused this issue? I'm assuming not since I don't believe either gets called until the test is actually started building (which should be logged in the console output).

Notes:

- MAXTHREADS is 10 (2 nodes - tests run in parallalel)
- Task getting run is `chrome(Type: Test)`

Any ideas or advice would be great.

Thanks,
Darwin